# Middle Grade Fantasy Novel Boy and Girl Travel to Two Worlds, Snow Kingdom and Ice Dragon?

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Been looking for this book for ages. It was a middle grade novel I probably read between 2008 and 2011. I remember two protagonists with split POV's, a boy and a girl, magically transported to two different fantasy worlds via book or magic rings. The girl went to a snowy fantasy kingdom and was forced to work as a maid for an evil snow queen. The boy I *believe* met a toy maker or wood carver and went on an adventure with him. Might have included a dragon trapped under an ice skating rink? Please advise!

P.S. Not The Magician's Nephew! That's a lot of people's first suggestion.

Comment: I thought it might be "Every heart a Doorway" or some other book in Wayward Children series but it doesn't match the timeline. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayward_Children

Comment: Do you remember if it was a stand-alone book, or part of a series. Or how large the book itself was (200 page summer novel or 800 page door stopper?) I could make parts of this fit into a Robin Hobb but it would be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: "Middle grade" as in unremarkable quality, or school year market targeting?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SF & F! Do you perhaps remember any of the names in the story, the author, or any other story details?

Comment: I seem to remember stand alone, and it would have been written for a middle school audience. The snow kingdom aspect stood out the most to me - maybe a scene with a carriage over an icy lake?